# How to layer in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have the following TikZ figure, and its output is shown pictorially below. My issue is that I want to extend the figure in such a way that below and outside of the overlay "Expressive FE" there is another overlay, and inside the new overlay there is only one node "WP4". So basically there should be two non-intersecting overlays inside "Project Overview", the one that I already have "Expressive FE", and below it another overlay. I already tried to do something about it (using the comment out lines below), however it messes the figure completely. Any ideas how to achieve that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{relsize}

\definecolor{cbg}{HTML}{fdf6e3} 
\definecolor{c1}{HTML}{CB4B16}
\definecolor{c2}{HTML}{586E75}
\definecolor{c3}{HTML}{6C71C4}
\definecolor{c4}{HTML}{D33682}

\newlength{\mynodedist}
\setlength{\mynodedist}{2pt}

\newlength{\mytextwidth}
\setlength{\mytextwidth}{50pt}

\newlength{\mytextheight}
\setlength{\mytextheight}{50pt}

\newcommand{\filllegendentry}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape] \filldraw[draw=#1, fill=#1, thin] (0,0) rectangle (0.8,0.4); \end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand{\legendentry}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape] \filldraw[pattern color=#1, draw=#1, fill=#1, pattern=#2, thin] (0,0) rectangle (0.8,0.4); \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1.4,
    transform shape,
    node distance=\mynodedist,
    outer sep=0pt, 
    pqfe/.style={
        draw=none,
        fill=c10!50,
        rounded corners,
        font={\scriptsize},
        align=center,
        text width=0.5\mytextwidth,
        minimum height=0.5\mytextheight-0.5\mynodedist
    },
    adapt/.style={
        draw=none,
        fill=c4!50,
        rounded corners,
        font={\scriptsize},
        align=center,
        text width=0.5\mytextwidth,
        minimum height=0.5\mytextheight-0.5\mynodedist
    },
    wp1/.style={
        pqfe,
        draw=cbg,
        fill=c1,
        minimum height=0.5\mytextwidth-0.5\mynodedist,
        text width=3\mytextwidth
    },
    wp2/.style={
        wp1,
        fill=c2,
        text width=3\mytextwidth+\mynodedist
    },
    wp3/.style={
        wp2,
        fill=c3,
        text width=3\mytextwidth+\mynodedist
    },
    wp4/.style={
        wp3,
        fill=c4,
        text width=3\mytextwidth+\mynodedist
    },
    dummy/.style={
        pqfe,
        minimum height=0.5\mytextwidth-0.5\mynodedist
    },
]
  \node[dummy] (dummy) {~};
  \node[dummy, below=of dummy] (dummy2) {~};
  \node[dummy, below=of dummy2] (dummy3) {~};
  \node[pqfe, anchor=north] at (dummy.north) (pqfe) {~};
%  \node[adapt, below=of pqfe] (adapt) {~};
  \node[wp1, anchor=north west] at (dummy.north west) (wp1) {WP1\\{\smaller (Upper Bounds)}};
  \node[wp2, anchor=north west] (wp2) at (dummy2.north west) {WP1\\{\smaller (Lower Bounds)}};
  \node[wp3, anchor=north west] (wp3) at (dummy3.north west) {WP3\\{\smaller (New Assumptions and Security Models)}}; 
%  \node[wp4, below=of wp3] (wp4) {WP4\\{\smaller (Adaptive Security)}};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \filldraw[pqfe,fill=c2] ([xshift=-4\mynodedist,yshift=16\mynodedist]pqfe.north west) 
                            -- ([xshift=5\mynodedist,yshift=16\mynodedist]wp1.north east) 
                            -- ([xshift=4\mynodedist,yshift=-4\mynodedist]wp3.south east)
                            -- ([xshift=-4\mynodedist,yshift=-4\mynodedist]wp3.south west)
                            -- cycle;
  \filldraw[pqfe,fill=c10!50] ([xshift=-2\mynodedist,yshift=8\mynodedist]pqfe.north west) 
                            -- ([xshift=7\mynodedist-30pt,yshift=8\mynodedist]wp1.north east) 
                            -- ([xshift=6\mynodedist-30pt,yshift=-2\mynodedist]wp3.south east)
                            -- ([xshift=-2\mynodedist,yshift=-2\mynodedist]wp3.south west)
                            -- cycle;   
%  \filldraw[adapt,fill=c2] ([xshift=-4\mynodedist,yshift=16\mynodedist]adapt.north west) 
%                            -- ([xshift=5\mynodedist,yshift=16\mynodedist]wp4.north east) 
%                            -- ([xshift=4\mynodedist,yshift=-4\mynodedist]wp4.south east)
%                            -- ([xshift=-4\mynodedist,yshift=-4\mynodedist]wp4.south west)
%                            -- cycle;
%  \filldraw[adapt,fill=c10!50] ([xshift=-2\mynodedist,yshift=8\mynodedist]adapt.north west) 
%                            -- ([xshift=7\mynodedist-30pt,yshift=8\mynodedist]wp4.north east) 
%                            -- ([xshift=6\mynodedist-30pt,yshift=-2\mynodedist]wp4.south east)
%                            -- ([xshift=-2\mynodedist,yshift=-2\mynodedist]wp4.south west)
%                            -- cycle;                                            
\end{pgfonlayer}

\node[font=\color{white},above=of wp1, anchor=south, xshift=-0pt, yshift=7\mynodedist] {\scriptsize Project Overview (Post-Quantum FE)};
\node[font=\color{black},above=of pqfe, anchor=south west, xshift=-15pt, yshift=-\mynodedist] {\scriptsize Expressive FE};
%\node[font=\color{black},below=of pqfe, anchor=south west, xshift=-15pt, yshift=-\mynodedist] {\scriptsize Adaptively-Secure FE};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{High-Level Project Overview}
\label{fig:overview}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check the [`fit`](https://tikz.dev/library-fit) and [`backgrounds`](https://tikz.dev/library-backgrounds) libraries?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Nope, but checking them now I'm not sure how I can use them in this case.

Comment: Hm, I am not fully sure how you want the final diagram to look like. Could you maybe add a drawing to show how you wish the rectangles to overlap?

Comment: @JasperHabicht I can try, but will be hard to draw. First requirement is that I have the gray box "Project Overview", so everything else needs to be inside it. Then, second requirement is that below (but not inside!) "Expressive FE" overlay I want to have another overlay called "Adaptively-Secure FE", and inside this second overlay I want to have a new node (similar to WP1/WP2/WP3), but it is named "WP4". So basically imagine having another copy of "Expressive FE" overlay underneath it, but instead of 3 nodes inside it will have 1. Does this clear it up a bit?

Comment: I think I got what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{lowerbackground}
\pgfsetlayers{lowerbackground, background, main}

\definecolor{cbg}{HTML}{66CCFF} 
\definecolor{c1}{HTML}{CB4B16}
\definecolor{c2}{HTML}{586E75}
\definecolor{c3}{HTML}{6C71C4}
\definecolor{c4}{HTML}{D33682}
\definecolor{c10}{HTML}{000000}

\newlength{\mynodedist}
\setlength{\mynodedist}{2pt}

\newlength{\mytextwidth}
\setlength{\mytextwidth}{50pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1.4,
    transform shape,
    node distance=\mynodedist,
    outer sep=0pt, 
    pqfe/.style={
        draw=none,
        fill=c10!50,
        rounded corners,
        font={\scriptsize},
        align=center,
    },
    wp1/.style={
        pqfe,
        draw=white,
        fill=c1,
        text width=3\mytextwidth
    },
    wp2/.style={
        wp1,
        fill=c2,
    },
    wp3/.style={
        wp1,
        fill=c3,
    },
    wp4/.style={
        wp1,
        fill=c4,
    },
    legend/.style={
        font={\scriptsize}
    }
]

  \node[text=white, legend] (legend1) {Project Overview (Post-Quantum FE)};
  \node[below=of legend1, legend] (legend2) {Expressive FE};

  \node[wp1, below=of legend2] (wp1) {WP1\\{\smaller (Upper Bounds)}};
  \node[wp2, below=of wp1] (wp2) {WP1\\{\smaller (Lower Bounds)}};
  \node[wp3, below=of wp2] (wp3) {WP3\\{\smaller (New Assumptions and Security Models)}}; 

  \node[below=10pt of wp3, legend] (legend3) {Adaptively-Secure FE};

  \node[wp4, below=of legend3] (wp4) {WP4\\{\smaller (Adaptive Security)}};

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node[pqfe, fit={(legend2) (wp3)}, fill=cbg] (fit1) {};
    \node[pqfe, fit={(legend3) (wp4)}, fill=cbg] (fit2) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{lowerbackground}
    \node[pqfe, fit={(legend1) (fit2)}, fill=c10!50] (fit3) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{High-Level Project Overview}
\label{fig:overview}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed the `pgfgantt` package which you don't really use and replaced it by `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`. I also loaded the `fit` library and defined three layers, two of which are to be understood as backgrounds that sit behind the main layer.

I cleaned up the styles a bit, since you actually only need to define the width of the inner nodes and the node distance thanks to the `fit` library.

Then, I just place all the nodes, including the "legend" nodes below each other and use the background layers and the `fit` library to position the larger rectangles.

---

With some adjustments as per your comment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{lowerbackground}
\pgfsetlayers{lowerbackground, background, main}

\definecolor{cbg}{HTML}{66CCFF} 
\definecolor{c1}{HTML}{CB4B16}
\definecolor{c2}{HTML}{586E75}
\definecolor{c3}{HTML}{6C71C4}
\definecolor{c4}{HTML}{D33682}
\definecolor{c10}{HTML}{000000}

\newlength{\mynodedist}
\setlength{\mynodedist}{2pt}

\newlength{\mytextwidth}
\setlength{\mytextwidth}{50pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1.4,
    transform shape,
    node distance=\mynodedist,
    outer sep=0pt, 
    pqfe/.style={
        draw=none,
        fill=c10!50,
        rounded corners,
        font={\scriptsize},
        align=center,
    },
    wp1/.style={
        pqfe,
        draw=white,
        fill=c1,
        text width=3\mytextwidth
    },
    wp2/.style={
        wp1,
        fill=c2,
    },
    wp3/.style={
        wp1,
        fill=c3,
    },
    wp4/.style={
        wp1,
        fill=c4,
    },
    legend/.style={
        text width=3\mytextwidth,
        font={\scriptsize}
    }
]

  \node[text=white, legend, align=center] (legend1) {Project Overview (Post-Quantum FE)};
  \node[below=of legend1, legend] (legend2) {Expressive FE};

  \node[wp1, below=of legend2] (wp1) {WP1\\{\smaller (Upper Bounds)}};
  \node[wp2, below=of wp1] (wp2) {WP1\\{\smaller (Lower Bounds)}};
  \node[wp3, below=of wp2] (wp3) {WP3\\{\smaller (New Assumptions and Security Models)}}; 

  \node[below=10pt of wp3, legend] (legend3) {Adaptively-Secure FE};

  \node[wp4, below=of legend3] (wp4) {WP4\\{\smaller (Adaptive Security)}};

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node[pqfe, fit={(legend2) (wp3)}, fill=cbg, inner xsep=-20pt, xshift=-24pt] (fit1) {};
    \node[pqfe, fit={(legend3) (wp4)}, fill=cbg, inner xsep=-20pt, xshift=-24pt] (fit2) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{lowerbackground}
    \node[pqfe, fit={(legend1) (fit2)}, fill=c10!50] (fit3) {};
  \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{High-Level Project Overview}
\label{fig:overview}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I wanted. Is it possible to left align the header text of the two overlays (i.e., "Expressive FE" and "Adaptively-Secure FE")? Also can one have the inner nodes, the ones with WP be longer than the overlay (like in my original post)?

Comment: @pixel Sure, see my edit.

Answer (score 5):

With just these three layers we can get away with

- using the built-in layers of each path
- and a somewhat slightly redundant loop for the middle layer.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, chains}
\newcommand*\legendset{\pgfqkeys{/legend}}
\definecolor{cbg}{HTML}{66CCFF} 
\definecolor {c1}{HTML}{CB4B16}
\definecolor {c2}{HTML}{586E75}
\definecolor {c3}{HTML}{6C71C4}
\definecolor {c4}{HTML}{D33682}
\definecolor{c10}{HTML}{000000}
\legendset{
  /tikz/legendset/.code=\legendset{#1},
  node distance/.initial=.2em,
  extra node distance/.initial=.7em,
  text width/.initial=\YouNeedToSetATextWidth,
  every title/.style={
    text width/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/legend/text width},
    align=center, path only},
  every header/.style={
    /legend/every title,
    yshift=-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/legend/extra node distance}),
    text depth=+0pt, text height=+.7em},
  title 1/.style={/legend/every header, text=white},
  title 2/.style={/legend/every header, align=left},
  title 3/.style={/legend/every title, draw=white, rounded corners},
  every rectangle/.style={rounded corners, fill},
  title 1 rectangle/.style={/legend/every rectangle, c10!50},
  @title 1 rectangle/.style={
    xshift/.expanded=-.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}),
    inner xsep/.expanded=1.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}),
    yshift/.expanded=-.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}),
    inner ysep/.expanded=1.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep})},
  title 2 rectangle/.style={
    /legend/every rectangle, /legend/less text width=5em, cbg},
  reset counter/.code=\setcounter{legendcounter}{0},
  step  counter/.code=\stepcounter{legendcounter},
  set inner colors/.style={
    /utils/exec=\def\pgfmathcounter{0},
    /utils/temp/.style={
      /legend/inner title \pgfmathcounter/.append style={fill={##1}},
      /utils/exec=\edef\pgfmathcounter{\pgfinteval{\pgfmathcounter+1}}},
    /utils/temp/.list={#1}},
}
\newcounter{legendcounter}
\makeatletter
\legendset{less text width/.style={
  xshift={-(#1)/2},
  text width/.expanded={\tikz@text@width-(#1)}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\tikzlegend[2][]{%
  \path[% no ; at the end → \tikzlegend needs to end with ;
    legendset={reset counter,#1},
    node distance=\pgfkeysvalueof{/legend/node distance},
    start chain=legend going below]
    foreach[count=\iA] \TitleA/\listA in {#2}{
      node[/legend/title 1, on chain] (legendA-\iA) {\TitleA}
      foreach[count=\iB] \TitleB/\listB in \listA{
        node[/legend/title 2, on chain] (legendB-\iB) {\TitleB}
        foreach \Title/\subTitle in \listB{
          node[/legend/title 3,
               /legend/inner title \thelegendcounter/.try,
               /legend/step counter, on chain] (legendB-\iB-last)
            {\Title\\{\footnotesize(\subTitle\unskip)}}}}
      [behind path]
      node[/legend/title 1 rectangle,
           /legend/@title 1 rectangle,
           fit=(legendA-\iA)(\tikzchaincurrent)]{}
      foreach[count=\iB] \TitleB/\listB in \listA{
        node[fit=(legendB-\iB)(legendB-\iB-last), /legend/title 2 rectangle]{}}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz
\tikzlegend[
  text width=width("Project Overview (Post-Quantum FE)"),
  set inner colors={c1, c2, c3, c4}
]{
  Project Overview (Post-Quantum FE)/{
    Expressive FE/{
      WP1/Upper Bounds,
      WP1/Lower Bounds,
      WP3/New Assumptions and Security Models
    },
    Adaptively-Secure FE/{
      WP4/Adaptive Security
    }% ← these % are necessary
  }%   ← these % are necessary
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]